# FQL - How to retrieve all the public post/photo with a certain caption?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I know that there is limitation for FB to search for hashtag (#).
However, is there any way I can retrieve all the public photo/post that contain certain caption? such as "Selfie2014"

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, because in the `stream` table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) you need to make use of of an indexable field, which are either

- filter_key
- post_id
- source_id

So there's no way to get the posts of **all** users.